# How to run the sub directory test list in VSMDI file using command line

Tags: mstest

I want to run specific sub-directory test list in VSMDI file from command line.
for example:

```
sanity
-> basic
-> basic1
functionality
-> func1
-> func2
```

There are 2 main test lists sanity and functionality, I want to run using the mstest command line only the sanity->basic2

Command line that i'm using today:

```
"\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testmetadata:"Auto.vsmdi" /testlist:"Sanity" /resultsfile:result.trx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "/" to separate the test lists in the test list hierarchy as in:

```
"/testlist:OuterList/InnerList"
```